# Is it a good idea to use Kafka to get the same data (JSON) to thousands of users (desktop clients) at the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture

We want to send real-time signals (intermittent, occurring once every few minutes to hours) to thousands of users simultaneously. (like fan-out pattern)

There are multiple types of these signals, and each user can subscribe to multiple signals.
The way we've currently devised to do this is to use Kafka.

We separate each signal into a producer, each topic into a partition, and each user into a consumer group.

Is this form of architecture suitable for our purposes?

We have no experience building such a dataflow and have been studying Kafka, Redis, and firebase cloud messaging (our client is a python app, so it doesn't fit) for this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used, sure, but JSON would be slower than other binary formats like Protobuf or Avro

You could also use other tools like MQTT brokers, which are more frequently used in IOT scenarios